# Select rows from 2 tables in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

Need to select name,domain from table 1, than I need a sum of values from a column from table 2 with condition table1.id = table2.

Table 2 does not have the same number of columns.

I have tried joining 2 queries with UNION and UNION ALL, but i keep getting the same problem of different number of columns.

```
$rows = $test->query('select domain,name from customers 
UNION 
select SUM(customer_id) from main.rentals,main.customers where customer_id = customers.id');
```

Expected would be `"User's Name" - "domain" - "number of rentals(integer)"`

> Warning: SQLite3::query(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, SELECTs to the left and right of UNION do not have the same number of result columns

Comment: Looks like you want a JOIN, not a UNION.

Comment: @Jonnix if i do join i don't get integer value from second part of the query.

Comment: What query are you trying with a join? There's no reason you can't get the sum using a JOIN. Vidal's answer points out that you probably wanted COUNT too.

Comment: union can only unite sql results horizontally which have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SUM, it will sum all ids, for example if you have a customer ID of 10 and it shows 5 times the result will be 50. In the other hand if you use count it will count the rows that that id was shown. That's why we are doing a group by. You may tweak it to fill your specific needs, but this is one way to achieve what you want.

```
$query = "
SELECT
   domain,
   name,
   count(customer_id) as Total
FROM
   customers
left join main.rentals on customers.id = customer_id
GROUP BY
   customer_id
";

$test->query($query );
```

Comment: thank you very much, just as i saw your response i saw that that i was summing up all the values. Thank you again!